# React-native: iOS App Crashes in Launch screen on device with Namespace SPRINGBOARD

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

When I am running my React-native project on iPhone 6 device, The application is staying in the launch for a while(close to 20-30 secs) and then the app crashes . Does anybody know how to fix the crash.

The crashlog i got is like this:

> **Termination Reason**: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
>   **Termination Description**: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.organization.appName exhausted real (wall clock)
>   time allowance of 19.82 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground |
>   ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create |
>   WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed
>   total CPU time (seconds): 20.760 (user 20.760, system 0.000), 52%
>   CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.191, 0% CPU" | ).

I have check few Q's from SO but they did not fix my problem.

Comment: Please explain to me the order of the project creation and execution.

Comment: Project is created like react-native init AppNam linked vector-icons, and executed as opening the xcode and ran it on a iPhone 6 device.

Comment: `react-native init AppNam` => `cd AppNam` => `npm install vectoricon` => `react-native link vectoricon` => `open simulator` => `react-native run-ios`  Is this the right order? Is the environment mac environment?

Comment: @hongdevelop : react-native link vectoricon, after this open .xcodeproj and run from Xcode

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue this morning without any project or OS changes since a working build yesterday.

My problem was that my phone had been connected to a different wifi network, so when it made a synchronous call to make sure the React Native Packager was running, it didn't get a reply.

Try toggling wifi and make sure everything is on the same network.

See also: [React Native ios app crashes when run outside of xcode with failed to scene-create after 19.88s error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616804/react-native-ios-app-crashes-when-run-outside-of-xcode-with-failed-to-scene-crea)

Comment: I have tried but didn't work, I have fixed with commenting debugger line